# need to pass the php value to javascript

Tags: php, javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to pass JavaScript variables to PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1917576/how-to-pass-javascript-variables-to-php)

Here below my code:

```
function disablefields(){ 

var suresh=[<?php echo $cryo_1kl_18_orig_jan; ?>];

if (document.getElementById('checkboxA').checked == 1){

document.getElementById('cryo_1kl_18_rev_jan').disabled=''; 
document.getElementById('cryo_1kl_18_rev_jan').value='**i want pass the php value here**';

}
```

I want to pass the php value to javascript...

Comment: what type of variable is `$cryo_1kl_18_orig_jan;` an array?

Answer (score 0):

```
function disablefields()
{ 
     var suresh=[<?php //echo $cryo_1kl_18_orig_jan; ?>];

    if (document.getElementById('checkboxA').checked == 1) {
        document.getElementById('cryo_1kl_18_rev_jan').disabled=''; 
        document.getElementById('cryo_1kl_18_rev_jan').value='<?=$your_value?>';
    }
```

Comment: hey really great... with in 22 seconds i got a reply.. Great Mr. Dainis Abols.

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById('cryo_1kl_18_rev_jan').value='<?php echo $php_value;?>';
```